# Will it hurt to run a django application and its static files(for a very small or demo site) on a single apache web server

Tags: django

I've got some small company websites(very less traffic) and a demo site for clients. Currently, I use apache to serve the django application and nginx for its static files. But, I think it would not hurt to serve the static files too using the same apache server (consideriing the sites have low traffic).

Am I wrong?

Comment: You could also serve django from nginx using uWSGI.

Comment: what's the advantage to 'serve django from nginx using uWSGI'

Comment: what's the advantage to 'serve django from apache' ? both have pros and cons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason *of itself* to think that using apache for both elements would be problematic. For example, this is the configuration provided by dreamhost by default.